# Redirect to "500.shtml" after clear cache drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have a site in drupal 7 which work perfectly for me. But recently I cleared my all cache from admin now the some page are redirect to "500.shtml" page.
Can anyone tell me what wrongs with the site?
I got in the log messages

Type    page not found

Date    Saturday, January 28, 2017 - 03:02

Location    http://localhost/kom/500.shtml/
Referrer

Message 500.shtml

Severity    warning

Hostname    110.225.215.185

Operations

This page is created by views.
and if I change the path then it works.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you with this little information. Check the server logs or drupal logs. Maybe you changed something in a template which broke the site but you didn't notice because you were still serving the working cached version of it.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for reply. I have created a view field template file then clear the cache but. pages goes to page not found. After that I delete the recently added file. Also upgrade the modules and core version of the drupal but the problem remain the same. And there is "500.shtml" message in the logs